# 12V 20A: What to do for high heat

Tags: voltage, wire, amperage, watts

I have 4 DC motors. they each require about 12V 9A DC (108W each), and have a potential draw of up to 12V 20A each (240W each) stall current.

I am using 22 AWG insulated wire. The length of the wire, per motor terminal is about 1.2 ft.

This is all on a small(ish) sized robot.

I need to know what kind of wire I need (per motor terminal) in order to prevent wire insulation melting or fires, with wattage like that in mind

Comment: What's the max starting current? for all motors?

Comment: Is that 80 amps total or 80 amps for each motor? Your comment revealing the nature of the project and the length of wire involved should be added to the question.

Comment: Locked rotor current far more (5~10x)than rated current and that is what is used for full acceleration start current.

Comment: Will you be using the wiring as fuse?   
If not, your fuse determines which size AWG you may use.

Comment: Hmmm.  What kind of battery fits in a "smallish" robot and can provide that kind of current long enough to melt wires?

Comment: I will not be using a fuse @Jeroen3

Comment: For 9 Amps, you should use at least #16 wire - #22 is much too small.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must be sure to select an adequate wire size for the current considering the temperature in the area where the wires are located. Also make sure that the wires are adequately protected from mechanical damage. Make sure that the wire connections are enclosed or otherwise protected from coming in contact with anything that would cause a short circuit. The connections must be tight and connected from corrosion. There must be protection from excess current due to motor overloading or short circuit.

You should probably use 14 AWG or larger depending on the insulation. For a vehicle, you should probably use finely stranded wire. If you use a high temperature insulation, you can use a little smaller wire, but you may need to be concerned about the mechanical strength of the wire and insulation.

I would be inclined to use 16 AWG with 27/30 stranding in silicone insulation covered with fiberglas braid. Or perhaps this: [https://www.amazon.com/BNTECHGO-Silicone-Flexible-Strands-Stranded/dp/B00TG1TRL2/ref=sr_1_12?dchild=1&keywords=silicone+insulated+wire&qid=1594775032&sr=8-12](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00TG1TRL2)

Using high temperature insulation allows a smaller wire gauge to be used. That offers the advantage of leads that are easier to work with, lighter weight and more flexible. The disadvantage is that any material that comes in contact with the wire must be capable of withstanding that same temperature without damage. Silicon insulation is rated 150C to 200C. SEW seems designate 200C silicon with a braided fiberglass outer protecting layer to abrasion resistance. Teflon insulation is rated 200C to 250C. TGGT seems to designate 250C insulation with a fiberglass cover. SRMC seems to designate 150C silicon insulation with no outer cover. Silicone insulation with no fiberglas cover would have better abrasion protection.

The Amazon product linked above has 200C silicon insulation with no outer cover. It has very fine stranding. The combination of very fine stranding and no outer cover makes it very flexible. I mentioned it because it seems to be easily available in sort lengths.

I would think that the motor controllers could not withstand the stall current for more that a minute or so. You might want to use 18 AWG wire for mechanical strength, but you will probably not get it above 150C. You probably don't need to select the wire based on heat. You will need to decide if you need the best abrasion resistance and how difficult it is to get the total length wire that you want to buy.

Comment: So do you think, heat wise, that TGGT wire is better, or SEW or SRML wire is better? @Charles Cowie

Answer (score 1):

The NEC requires at least #3 AWG wire for 80 amps.

You may need larger wires depending on the length of cable and allowable voltage loss.  With 80 amps in #3 cable, you will have a 3% voltage loss in a 12 ft two conductor cable on a 12 volt circuit.  For a 30 ft cable run, you'd need #00 wire for a 3% voltage loss.

**Edit**
If each motor only draws 36 amp, you can use #10 AWG wire to each motor.  #12 or even #14 may be adequate if the wires are in open air, or for low duty cycle - check the wire temperature while the motors are operating.

Comment: Ok. the cable length for my project is about 1.2ft. This is on a small(ish) robot, so I probably won't be able to go the full AWG

Comment: I lived by NEC code for many decades, and there is a reason they have strict rules about amps vs. wire gauge, and wire insulation type. #4 AWG could get hot at 80 amps, but Teflon insulation can take that heat.+1

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to get away (temperature wise) with as small as AWG20 with PTFE insulation if you are willing to allow the wire temperature to go to a rather toasty 200°C. That's for 20A or so, assuming no current path is shared between motors.

Voltage drop will be large (about 1 volt for a 2.5 foot round trip), you'll lose some torque, so use a higher gauge if possible, and don't bundle even two of the wires together if they're on the smaller end of the sizes.

If you're using low performance wire with PVC etc. insulation rated at lower temperatures as suggested above, the insulation will drip off the wire potentially causing shorts, and nasty chlorine gas may be emitted.